# Isolate with FutureBuilder not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, dart-isolates

I am trying to load a big file using FutureBuilder and isolates using below code.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

// utils
const fileName = 'assets/files/big_file.txt';
const smallFileName = 'assets/files/small_file.txt';
//
Future<String> loadBigFile(String fileName) async {
  return rootBundle.loadString(fileName);
}


Future<String> loadFileUsingThread(String fileName) async {
  return await compute(loadBigFile, fileName);
}
```

and Later when I try to call the below

```
Future<String>? _future;
_future = loadFileUsingThread(smallFileName);
```

```
            child: FutureBuilder<String>(
              initialData: '',
              future: loadFileUsingThread(smallFileName),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                    snapshot.hasData) {
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
                  );
                }
                return Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'File Read Error ${snapshot.error}',
                ));
              },
            ),
          )
```

I get the below error

```
Unhandled Exception: Binding has not yet been initialized.
The "instance" getter on the ServicesBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has been initialized.
Typically, this is done by calling "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" or "runApp()" (the latter calls the former). Typically this call is done in the "void main()" method. The "ensureInitialized" method is idempotent; calling it multiple times is not harmful. After calling that method, the "instance" getter will return the binding.
In a test, one can call "TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" as the first line in the test's "main()" method to initialize the binding.
If ServicesBinding is a custom binding mixin, there must also be a custom binding class, like WidgetsFlutterBinding, but that mixes in the selected binding, and that is the class that must be constructed before using the "instance" getter.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share you `main()` entry point function

Comment: I couldn't reproduce. maybe try to rebuild the app...

Comment: I did everything. stuck with this for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

`rootBundle.loadString` [implementation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle/loadString.html) uses isolate to decode. I think there is no need to use isolate again.

> The function expects the stored string to be UTF-8-encoded as Utf8Codec will be used for decoding the string. If the string is larger than 50 KB, the decoding process is delegated to an isolate to avoid jank on the main thread.

```
Future<String> loadString(String key, { bool cache = true }) async {
  final ByteData data = await load(key);
  if (data == null) {
    throw FlutterError('Unable to load asset: $key');
  }
  // 50 KB of data should take 2-3 ms to parse on a Moto G4, and about 400 μs
  // on a Pixel 4.
  if (data.lengthInBytes < 50 * 1024) {
    return utf8.decode(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  }
  // For strings larger than 50 KB, run the computation in an isolate to
  // avoid causing main thread jank.
  return compute(_utf8decode, data, debugLabel: 'UTF8 decode for "$key"');
}
```